# Keeping bindings when putting a flowdocument through pagination

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0, reporting

I've been trying to build a simple reporting and printing system in WPF in .NET 4 and after countless hours of trawling SO and various online tutorials I have the following (simplified) setup that is supposed to take a flowdocument containing the report template, add a data source as datacontext, put it through pagination and end up with something that can be displayed/printed.

The report is laid out in a flowdocument in a separate content file (DefaultReport.xaml):

```
<FlowDocument xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Paragraph FontFamily="Arial">
        <Run Text="1"/>        
        <Run Text="{Binding Path=MyText}"/>
        <Run Text="3"/>        
    </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

The datacontext is a simple object:

```
private class MyDataContext {
    public string MyText { get; set; }
}
```

This is loaded and put together like so:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead("DefaultReport.xaml")) {
    FlowDocument document = (FlowDocument)XamlReader.Load(stream);                
    document.DataContext = new MyDataContext { MyText = "2" };

    flowReader.Document = document;           

    XpsDocument xpsDoc = LoadAsXPS(((IDocumentPaginatorSource)document).DocumentPaginator);
    fixedReader.Document = xpsDoc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
    xpsDoc.Close();
}
```

LoadAsXPS turns the flowdocument to a XpsDocument like so:

```
public XpsDocument LoadAsXPS(DocumentPaginator paginator) {
     MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
     Package docPackage = Package.Open(stream, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

     Uri uri = new Uri(@"memorystream://myXps.xps");
     PackageStore.AddPackage(uri, docPackage);
     XpsDocument xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(docPackage);

     xpsDoc.Uri = uri;
     XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDoc).Write(paginator);

     return xpsDoc;
 }
```

flowReader and fixedReader output the results of the whole operation and are defined in xaml as

```
 <FlowDocumentReader Name="flowReader" />
 <DocumentViewer Margin="0,10,0,0" Name="fixedReader" />
```

The end result is the following:

[image]

The upper half is the FlowDocumentReader I'm using for debugging. Everything works fine here.
The lower half is the DocumentViewer containing my paginated document and is what I need to get working properly.

How *exactly* can I preserve binding data through the pagination process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out 10 minutes after setting a bounty. Figures.

Apparently the dispatcher needs a little push to get things going after assigning the flowdocument datacontext:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle, new Action(() => { }));
```

Comment: I am having the same issue, could you kindly tell me where exactly in the code you added this line? I am using DocumentViewer. Thanks

Comment: RDV, after three and a half years I simply don't remember. According to my answer it must have been after document.DataContext = new MyDataContext { MyText = "2" };

Comment: Thanks Manos, though for me it is still not working :-(

Comment: This worked for me, I called the dispatcher right after setting the data context:
`document.DataContext = dataContext;
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle, new Action(() => {
    }));`